# C# OpenFiledialog multiselect string array

Tags: c#, dialog

I would like to store  file name selected in my string array.

Code:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       string filename ;
       string[] result = null;
       int i = 0;
      try                {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    foreach (String file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        result[i] = filename;
                        MessageBox.Show(result[i]); // only show the name of file
                        i = i + 1;

                    }                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.   Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Error code was: "the index is out of size of array"

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

You should only use an array if you know in advance how many items you are gonna add. You should work with a list so you can always add extra stuff to it. Because you never define the size of the array you get the error I believe.

if you dynamically are gonna add stuff you should maybe work with a list.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
```

when adding

```
result.add(filename);
```

to show

```
MessageBox.Show(result[i])
```

so your code would be

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   string filename ;
   List<string> result = new List<string>();
   int i = 0;
  try                {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                foreach (String file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    result.add(filename);
                    MessageBox.Show(result[i]); // only show the name of file
                    i = i + 1;

                }                  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.   Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `string[] result = null;`
If you change this to `string[] result = new string[3];` your solution will work fine but this is not the right approach instead use `List<String>`

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filename;
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                int i = 0;
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        foreach (String file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                        {
                            filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                            result.Add(filename);
                            MessageBox.Show(result[i]); // only show the name of file

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.   Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```